# QGIS does not load OSM data completely

Tags: openstreetmap, qgis-3, quickosm

I used QGIS 3.2 to load OSM data obtained from Geofabrik as

> Layer/ Add Layer/ Add Vector Layer

The problem is that QGIS does not show roads completely compared to the OpenStreetMap website. I converted the .osm format to .xml and searched for the ID of missing line segments from the OSM website. I found out the  tag with the specified ID exists in the XML file so the Geofabrik data is the same as OSM webpage. I also installed QuickOSM plugin in QGIS with no success of loading the whole data. Is it some bugs in QGIS or something else?

Comment: What data is missing?

Comment: @HeikkiVesanto because I'm working on polyline features, I've noticed some segments of streets and highways are missing.

Comment: [@nasser tahani](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/96541/nasser-tahani), can you please describe the area which you are exploring, as well as which level do you work with (continent, country, province etc.)? I am just curious when the last update was done by Geofabrik and whether the osm file includes tags that describe the visualization characteristics.

Comment: Osm_id of a problematic feature might help as well.

Comment: I got the data of Iran (country level) and particularly I'm working on Tehran city. I've checked the Osm_id of OpenStreetMap with XML and it exists. Hafez Avenue (182000227) is one of the problematic features. But I think the problem is related to QGIS loading OSM data.

Answer (score 2):

There must be something wrong with the dataset. I get the same broken import as you with `Add Vector Layer` and the QuickOSM plugin.

It might be related to topological errors (the OSM database does not care about them)  or node numbers not sorted.

Since you are interested in the Teheran area, you can clip the source file with this osmosis command:

```
osmosis.bat --read-pbf iran-latest.osm.pbf --bb left=51.1 right=51.7 bottom=35.5 top=35.9 --write-pbf bbox.osm.pbf
```

The result is only 7MB large, and loads quickly and complete in QGIS.

Answer (score 0):

I applied ArcGIS OSM editor and it loaded all points, lines, and polygons completely. I think for quick rendering, QGIS does not indicate/load the whole data which seems kind of bug.

Comment: If you think this is a bug, you can report it here: https://issues.qgis.org/. Bugs don't get fixed if no one reports them.